# Unable to build after updating Compose version to beta08

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

While building my code after updating from beta07 to beta08, the execution fails with NullPointerException.

Below is the complete stacktrace:

```
e: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.IrUtilsKt.getTypeSubstitutionMap(IrUtils.kt:548)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.IrUtilsKt.getTypeSubstitutionMap(IrUtils.kt:556)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitConstructorCall(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:168)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies

at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstructorCallImpl.accept(IrConstructorCallImpl.kt:28)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.acceptChildren(IrVariableImpl.kt:77)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:40)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitDeclaration(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitVariable(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:68)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitVariable(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitVariable(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:69)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitVariable(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitVariable(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.accept(IrVariableImpl.kt:74)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrContainerExpression.acceptChildren(IrBlock.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:104)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:173)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitContainerExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitContainerExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:225)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:122)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:48)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBranch.acceptChildren(IrWhen.kt:50)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBranch(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:213)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBranch(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitElseBranch(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:216)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElseBranch(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitElseBranch(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:217)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElseBranch(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElseBranch(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrElseBranchImpl.accept(IrWhenImpl.kt:69)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.acceptChildren(IrWhen.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:104)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:173)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitWhen(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:210)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitWhen(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:182)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitWhen(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:211)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitWhen(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitWhen(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.accept(IrWhen.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.acceptChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:104)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:173)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitMemberAccess(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:158)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitMemberAccess(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFunctionAccess(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:161)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitFunctionAccess(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitConstructorCall(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:167)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:135)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitConstructorCall(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:168)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitConstructorCall(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstructorCallImpl.accept(IrConstructorCallImpl.kt:28)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.acceptChildren(IrBody.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:86)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:192)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpressionBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:89)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpressionBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFunction.acceptChildren(IrFunction.kt:59)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:40)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitDeclaration(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFunction(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:49)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitFunction(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:52)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitSimpleFunction(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:53)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitSimpleFunction(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitSimpleFunction(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.acceptChildren(IrClass.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:40)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitDeclaration(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:43)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:44)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrContainerExpression.acceptChildren(IrBlock.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:104)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:173)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitContainerExpression(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitContainerExpression(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:225)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:122)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBlock(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBlock(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:48)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.acceptChildren(IrBody.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:86)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:192)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpressionBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:89)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitExpressionBody(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitExpressionBody(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.acceptChildren(IrField.kt:38)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:40)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitDeclaration(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitField(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:61)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitField(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:103)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitField(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:62)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitField(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitField(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.accept(IrField.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.acceptChildren(IrClass.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitDeclaration(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:40)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitDeclaration(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:43)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:44)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitClass(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.acceptChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitElement(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:229)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitPackageFragment(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:30)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitPackageFragment(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFile(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:37)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitFile(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFile(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:38)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitFile(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotator.visitFile(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:60)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.acceptChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:40)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.IrComposableAnnotatorKt.annotateComposableFunctions(IrComposableAnnotator.kt:56)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:116)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:140)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:592)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:212)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834
```

I have setup the gradle exactly as shown here :
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose#kts

```
android {
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.10"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-beta08"
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    freeCompilerArgs += "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies"
}
}
```

I made sure that my kotlin plugin is updated to the latest 1.5.10 version. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try to use without beta08

Comment: Its working with beta07, but I wanted to update to beta08; because I am facing an issue with LazyColumn which is fixed in beta08, so want to try the same.

Comment: can u try with kotlin 1.5.0

Comment: Compose beta08 specifically requires kotlin 1.5.10

Comment: sorry I mean 1.5.10, I guess u need to update kotlin and gradle in last version

Comment: I have kotlin and gradle updated, regarding Kotlin plugin, I've already mentioned in the question that its updated.

Comment: Which version are you using for `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin`  in your build.gradle?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"

Comment: @Ali_Waris Remove the flag: `freeCompilerArgs += "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies"` in your build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Tried that too. Still the same error :(

Comment: There's probably an open issue regarding this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190076603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the compose version to `"1.0.0-beta09"` fixed the issue. Project is building fine without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just update the Kotlin Version to 1.5.10 in the project level build.Gradle file

Comment: The kotlin version is already updated to 1.5.10. Still, facing the same error.

Comment: Did you try making a new dummy project to see if the error is in the built-in implementation or in your own?

Comment: And are you using the latest Bumblebee Canary?

Comment: I am using the latest Arctic Fox canary.

Comment: I think upgrade to the Bumblebee update. Also, try creating a new project, using the empty compose activity template and see if it compiles.

Comment: Issue was with the compose library itself. Updating to the latest beta09 fixed the issue.